# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method

Tags: python, django, file, file-upload, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file uploaded from HTML form via POST to Google Drive.
I was able to get the file name, file temp path, but it throws this error and the file is eventually not uploaded to Google Drive.

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class Submit(MissionSubmission):
    def get(self, request, mission_id):
        mission = MissionDetail.objects.all().filter(id=mission_id)[0]
        mission = newline_aware(mission)

        return render(request, 'home/submit.html', {'mission': mission})

    def post(self, request, mission_id):
        request.upload_handlers = [TemporaryFileUploadHandler(request=request)]
        return self._post(request, mission_id)

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def _post(self, request, mission_id):
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['filename']
        print(uploaded_file.name)
        print(uploaded_file.size)
        print(uploaded_file.temporary_file_path())
        print(uploaded_file.content_type)

        file_metadata = {'name': uploaded_file.name}
        media = MediaFileUpload(uploaded_file.temporary_file_path,
                                mimetype=uploaded_file.content_type)
        file = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                            media_body=media,
                                            fields='id').execute()
        print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))

        return HttpResponse("Hi")
```

Anyone knows what's wrong? This is what I get from the console.

```
(venv) marcus@marcus-RAVEN-SE:/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/unlock$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 08, 2020 - 17:44:18
Django version 3.0.5, using settings 'unlock.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[08/May/2020 17:44:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8283
[08/May/2020 17:44:22] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 200 135079
[08/May/2020 17:44:22] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 196315
[08/May/2020 17:44:22] "GET /static/images/CYCLogo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2020 17:44:22] "GET /static/images/TitleLogo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 110175
[08/May/2020 17:44:22] "GET /static/images/unlockBG.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 649451
[08/May/2020 17:44:26] "GET /mission/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6334
[08/May/2020 17:44:26] "GET /static/images/Lock.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2020 17:44:27] "GET /mission/submit/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 4496
Login.png
258917
/tmp/tmpnpz7epou.upload.png
image/png
Internal Server Error: /mission/submit/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/unlock/home/views.py", line 116, in post
    return self._post(request, mission_id)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/unlock/home/views.py", line 127, in _post
    media = MediaFileUpload(uploaded_file.temporary_file_path,
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/Programming/UnlockProject/System/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 575, in __init__
    fd = open(self._filename, "rb")
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not method
[08/May/2020 17:44:33] "POST /mission/submit/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 130268
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[08/May/2020 17:44:34] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2844
```

Since I'm able to get the details of uploaded_file, so I think the django part of the code has no issue, but it's the Google part of the code that is causing this error. But it really left me stranded, I got no idea what's wrong with it, everything seems just right just like in the Google documentation.

Update: I tried substituting the variable to be an actual path to an actual file, it works. So... is it possible that the uploaded_file.temporary_file_path() provided by Django is invalid?

Comment: can you share the full error code?

Comment: Hard to tell exactly on what line this error could be happening. Update the full error trace to the question.

Comment: Your error is when invoking the constructor for the `MediaFileUpload` object. Could you maybe tell us what are the variables you introducing yourself. Take a look at the [`create`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#create) and [`MediaFileUpload`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaFileUpload-class.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looking at your code and the error message is clear to me that you are actually passing the function (callable object) `temporary_file_path` instead of the `return` of that function.

Basically

```
temporary_file_path != temporary_file_path()
```

One (the first) is the function object and the other the actual file path.

Change your code to this and you should be good:

```
media = MediaFileUpload(uploaded_file.temporary_file_path(),
                                mimetype=uploaded_file.content_type)
```